# Apache Tika detecting docx mimetype wrong

Tags: apache-tika

I'm using Apache tika to see if the file extension matches the actual mimetype.For example, if a file is named .pdf but is actually an .exe, it would return false.

I send in a .docx with the mimetype

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Tika does a .detect on the content and says that it is a

> application/x-tika-ooxml

Any idea what could be wrong? Obviously the method returns false in this case cause they're not a match.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with a random docx file, works fine with 1.18 and 1.21 - both output application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: How are you sending Apache Tika the file? With what code? How did you package / run Tika? Maven? Tika App? Server? Other?

Comment: @Gagravarr It's being sent to tika as a byte array.

Comment: @maio290 I'm using 1.13 could this be the issue?

Comment: Sent how? To what? You haven't posted any code, you haven't said how you use Tika, what packaging you use etc. Without that we will struggle to help you!

Comment: I can just guess that your version is the error. Since 1.17 application/x-tika-ooxml got removed from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser